# How to test or view the installed OSGI bundles in Apache Ace

Tags: java, apache, osgi, tomcat7, apache-ace

I have created the sample application with OSGI. I have deployed in the Apache Ace. It is in the `apache-ace-1.0.0-bin\server-allinone\store` path. How can I test/view the application?

```
For eg: http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp
```

[image]

How can I proceed after this? How can I Test the application?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the screenshot you've posted you have been following the "user guide" on the Apache ACE website: http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/user-guide.html

As soon as you've setup artifacts, features, distributions and a target, the next step is to actually run a target so the artifacts will be deployed to it. That part is described in the same document starting here: http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/user-guide.html#running-a-target

Once you have deployed your application succesfully, it should be active. Judging from the URL you post in your question, you have created some kind of web application. Remember that ACE itself runs on port 8080 by default, so that might be why you don't see your application running, but to better answer your question, you need to be more specific about the steps you took, what you expected and what actually happened.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer @Marcel Offermans.In my application I have followed the following steps.1) I have added the artifacts. 2) I have clicked the Add feature and gave the feature name and description.3) Drag the artifacts into the feature name. 4) I have clicked Add distribution button and added the name and description and drag the feature into it. 5) I have clicked the Add  target and added identifier name and drag the distributions into it. In the target I shows Three values registered, approved and idle. Please correct me if I am wrong and guide me the proceedings

Comment: So far so good. Did you actually start the target too? If so, it should get the software you provisioned to it, unless for some reason the software does not want to install. In that case, it tries to install, and does a rollback. Make sure that the set of bundles you deploy actually work together in a framework (with nothing else installed).

Comment: When I started the target it is not added into the target.